# Setting initial Kafka partition offsets

Tags: apache-kafka

**Short question**: Can you create a Kafka topic and specify the initial partition offsets?

**Context**: I'm evaluating the use of Kafka for a new system. I have messages that need to be stored for later retrieval with a global order that is the order in which the messages were pushed into Kafka. Since each Kafka message has an offset, I could directly use it as a range query key in the DB into which the consumer writes the messages.

Basically, it would be a poor man's sequence number. In other words, instead of maintaining a sequence number of each client, my Kafka consumer would track for each user the offset of the latest message and when writing into the DB include the offset of the previous message (we have multiple clients using the same partition, so the previous offset could be for a different client). I would store in the DB something like:

(client ID, offset, previous offset, data)

If a client sees a message with an unknown previous offset, it would query for it.

**Concerns**: With the previous setup if I ever move to another Kafka cluster, I need to basically:

1. Stop the producers.
2. Consume any backlog of the old cluster.
3. Create the topic in the new cluster in such a way that the offsets start off where they stopped in the old cluster.

Does Kafka support this? I couldn't see any switch for it in `kafka-topics.sh`. Is this a dumb strategy in general when using Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

Only consumers can seek to existing offsets.

When you create topics, the offsets always start at zero.

Records at offsets are immutable, and producers always append to the end of the partitions, and monotonically increase them

---

If you use Kafka Connect to write data into a database, you can use InsertField transform to add offset information while writing into a database.

You can also make Kafka consumers use an external offset store, with extra code